# Google Maps Changes the color of a KML

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a map that loads several KMZ layers. Even though the shapes have the same KML style (and fill color), Google Maps is giving them slightly different shades.

Here is an example where there are two shades of dark purple. You can also see that while my KML polygons are styled on a block level, Google Maps is cutting across blocks and applying its fill color on the tile level.

Is this a problem with the Google Maps KML rendering engine?  Is there a fix?

[image]

Comment: That is an artifact of the way Google Maps does load sharing of tiles between different servers (that creates the checkerboard pattern.  Was it a transient effect (is it still happening)? I doubt there is anything you can do about it, except perhaps serve your own tiles.

Comment: It is still happening.  Fortunately it isn't too bad - just a little weird!

Answer (score 0):

KML coloring is different to normal html hex/rgb color codes. the underlying colors on the map also affect the kml color used. the following color creator may help you http://www.zonums.com/gmaps/kml_color/ . The best way to resolve that tiling issue is to relaod kml and reapply after a few seconds. make sure you are not caching the kml, if so then delete and recache.